# How to restart process running on Ubuntu 14.x version

Tags: cron, ipython

I am new with Ubuntu. Please help me for this mentioned issue. This shaded area in attached image is my process that is running on Ubuntu 14.x version. It is python program which is reading a configuration file. When I am changing some configuration I always shut down **"kill [process ID]"** this process and start it. On new startup it takes new process ID.

[image: Process Image]

My client is non-technical guy he/she can not kill the process with changed ID and start it. I want such utility (command) that he/she can restart the process programmatically. what ever the process ID will be.

I have tried below thing:

**sudo restart scheduler.py 

 sudo restart python3 scheduler.py 

 sudo scheduler.py restart 

 sudo python3 scheduler.py restart**

All above tries are useless. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve what you desire is as follows:

```
pkill scheduler.py
python3 /path/to/scheduler.py
```

You can also put it in a shell script.

To stop the process:

```
#!/bin/bash

pkill scheduler.py

exit 0
```

And save it as `anyname1.sh`

To start the process:

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 /path/to/scheduler.py

exit 0
```

Now, save it as `anyname2.sh`

Then, run this command to make them executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/anyname1.sh
chmod +x /path/to/anyname2.sh
```

So, now, all your friend needs to do is double-click on those files and then click on `Run`.

**EDIT**: If the first script doesn't work as expected you may try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

kill -9 $(ps axf | grep scheduler.py | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following commands in the terminal however it is highly recommended to just kill the service and restart it.

```
/etc/init.d/SERVICE_NAME restart
```

or

```
service SERVICE_NAME restart
```